# Return string from an input file

Tags: c#

I have created the connection below, which creates a file last.txt, which in essence has a single entry. What i cannot do is read the file last.txt and return the entry in the file.

A) Do I need to create another method that reads the file and returns the entry?

B) Can I return it from the `Return` Method?

The code below works and does create the file last.txt.

Thanks

```
public static void Return()
{
    using (var conn = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***-dev-scan)(PORT=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=CONN)));User ID=EE;Password=***;Min Pool Size=2; Max Pool Size=35; Connection Lifetime=120"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select Statement";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\last.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int ColumnCount = reader.FieldCount;
        string ListOfColumns = string.Empty;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string value = reader[i].ToString();
                if (value.Contains(",")) value = "\"" + value + "\"";

                sb.Append(value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ") + ",");
            }
            sb.Length--; // Remove the last comma
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
        writer.Close();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Return is a [keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word) and should not be used for naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText` returns the text file content as string.

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\last.txt");
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) for details.

Comment: Remember that for very large files, the file is loaded completely into memory to read it. For large files, you should read the file piece by piece.
Possible occurrence of an OutOfMemoryException